# How to prevent StackOverflow error when changing values of two dependent DateTimePickers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, stack-overflow

I have the three `DateTimePicker`, where one of them is the interval between startdate and enddate. In a part of the code, I update `startdate.Value` and `enddate.Value`, whose `ValueChanged` events update `interval.Value`.

[image: DateTimePickers]

Everything works fine when the value in `interval` doesn't need to be changed manually. But when I need to change it manually, it causes a `StackOverflow` exception, because when `final.Value` is set, it causes interval's `ValueChanged` event to trigger, which changes `final.Value`, and so on.

This the ValueChanged handler for `startdate` and `enddate`:

```
    private void dates_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (startdate.Value < enddate.Value)
        {
            TimeSpan diff = enddate.Value - startdate.Value;
            DateTime newInterval = new DateTime(startdate.Value.Year, startdate.Value.Month, startdate.Value.Day, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
            if (interval.Value != newInterval)
                interval.Value = newInterval;
        }
    }
```

And this is the ValueChanged handler for `interval`, which causes the `StackOverflow` exception:

```
    private void interval_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int seconds = intervaloDP.Value.Hour * 3600 + intervaloDP.Value.Minute * 60 + intervaloDP.Value.Second;
        finalDP.Value = finalDP.Value.AddSeconds(seconds);
    }
```

Is there a way to change this code and make it work the way I need it to work?

Comment: `finalDP.Value = finalDP.Value.AddSeconds(seconds);` seems wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that there is always an exit condition:

```
var dtm = startDP.Value.AddSeconds(seconds);
if (dtm != finalDP.Value)
    finalDP.Value = dtm;
```

This way, the event won't fire if there is no change to make.

**UPDATE:** Changed code so that seconds are added to startDP, not finalDP.

Comment: Good approach, but I'm afraid the original code seems wrong, the seconds should be added to the startDp, not to finalDP

Comment: @leonbloy Top spot. :) Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are already doing the right thing by updating the interval only when needed:

```
   if (interval.Value != newInterval)  interval.Value = newInterval;
```

That should be enough to avoid the infinite loop of updates. But you are computing wrongly the other update:

```
 private void interval_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int seconds = intervaloDP.Value.Hour * 3600 + intervaloDP.Value.Minute * 60 + intervaloDP.Value.Second;
        // finalDP.Value = finalDP.Value.AddSeconds(seconds); //wrong
        finalDP.Value = startDP.Value.AddSeconds(seconds); 
    }
```

(BTW, you should define your desired behaviour when the interval crosses the `24:00:00` point)